# How to re-order cloumn in txt file?

Tags: python

I have a large txt file `sample.txt` with over 54000 columns. They are ordered like this:

```
1011001 1 1001164 981328 1 -9 A G G G G G C C A . . . .    
1011002 1 1001164 981328 1 -9 A G G G G G A C A . . . .
```

I need to re-order the columns as follows:

```
1 1011001 1001164 981328 1 -9 A G G G G G C C A . . . .
1 1011002 1001164 981328 1 -9 A G G G G G A C A . . . .
```

I.e I want the second column be the first one.

Is there some way for me to do this with Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, please format this with Markdown so it is more readable.

Comment: Are you using Qiime?  Or Mothur?  If you are using an existing sequencing toolkit, it may well contain code for converting between sequence file-types like this to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
elements=[]
with open(filename,"r") as f:
    for e in f.readlines():
        line = e.split(" ")
        line0 = line[0]
        line[0] = line[1]
        line[1] = line0
        elements.append(" ".join(line))
with open(filename,"w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(elements))
```

Alternatively, if the above code crashes due to file size, you can do everything at once like this:

```
with open(filename,"r") as f:
    with open(filename2,"w") as f2:
        for e in f.readlines():
            line = e.split(" ")
            line0 = line[0]
            line[0] = line[1]
            line[1] = line0
            f2.write(" ".join(line) + "\n")
```

... where `filename2` is some other filename.  Once you run the code, replace `filename` with `filename2`, and you are done.

Comment: after line 3 in first script it gave me this : File "<stdin>", line 2
    for e in f.readlines():
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Works fine for me. May want to try to re indent everything

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
   l=[' '.join([i.split()[1],i.split()[0],i.split()[2]])+'\n' for i in f.readlines()]
with open(filename,'w') as f:
   f.writelines(l)
```

Or in this case maybe:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
   l=[' '.join([i.split()[1],i.split()[0],i.split()[2:]])+'\n' for i in f.readlines()]
with open(filename,'w') as f:
   f.writelines(l)
```

Comment: While this is elegant, OP is (unless I am very mistaken) working with **massive** DNA sequencing files.  From my own personal experience with this type of data I would assume that OP probably wants to go line by line, rather than all at once in RAM.  (OR does Python do this lazily?)

Comment: I was going to do something like this, but you have to split `i` thrice, and there are 54000 columns, soo yeah.

Comment: it gave me this error   $ python re_order.py sample.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re_order.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open(9,"r") as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: @mary Try this: `with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f` instead of  `with open(9,"r")`

Comment: @mary Edited my answer, see the second code example in my answer

Answer (score 2):

With 54000 columns I would use regular expression, which is fast:

```
import re

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('sample_out.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    for line in f_in.readlines():
        g = re.findall(r'[^\s]+', line)
        if g:
            f_out.write(' '.join([g[1], g[0]] + g[2:]) + '\n')
```

Comment: $ python reorder.py sample.txt
  File "reorder.py", line 7
    f_out.write(' '.join([g[1], g[0], *g[2:]]) + '\n')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                  I get this error

Comment: @mary Probably you are using Python2, I updated my answer, It should work now.